# Faster way to fetch documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, java-8, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch documents from mongodb using Java mongo client.

```
cities.parallelStream().forEach(name -> {
        FindIterable result = collection.find(new BsonDocument().append("_source", new BsonString(name))
                .append("addressid", new BsonNull()), BsonDocument.class);

 ..... stream above docs using kafka producer ....
```

In the above snippet, `cities` is a `ArrayList` with approx size of 500 city names.
As per business logic, I need to process each city and get all the documents that has `addressId` value as `null`. Each city results around 10k-40k documents.

Although this code works but it takes very long time. `parallelStream()` helped to little extent but could not see much difference. I see only 2 Thread as per CloudWatch logs with parallelStream.

The same query which is executed from Robo3T hardly take 3 seconds for each city. Below is the query

```
db.getCollection('adresses').find({"_source":"Chicago", "addressid":null}
```

I am new to these concepts, Please help in understanding the best approaches to fetch data in parallel.

Comment: 500 cities is a different ask than a single city.   500 * 25000 (avg?) docs to be examine is 12.5million docs.   When you say "long time", how long?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti its taking around 5-6 hours, total docs = 8344826

Comment: 8344826/5.5 hours ~421 docs/sec; that's way too slow.  I just inserted 12,500,000 docs into a collection (500 cities X 25000 addrs) and did a find() to get all of them and that took 46 seconds on a MacBookPro.   `$group` by city and getting the count (25000, obviously) took 24.3 seconds.   What is the overall size of your docs and what is infra setup?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti 46seconds through MongoDb java client ? I see slowness only through java code. Through shell I dont see any issue.

Comment: I am modifying my multithreaded Java testbed.   Any indexes on `city` or `address`, what percent of `address` is `null`, and how big is each doc?   You are doing `find()` with no projection so the whole thing is coming back over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

Consider 500 cities X 25000 addresses for a total of 12,500,000 docs with this simple shape:

```js
{ city: "Cn", addr: "Am"}
```

where 0 < `n` < 499 and 0 < `m` < 10 (yes, addresses repeat).  **No indexes.**

A "no effort agg" running on the `mongo` CLI the same machine as the server (MacBookPro 2.7GHz quadcore 16G RAM c2013) runs fast:

```js
var nn = 0;
db.foo.aggregate().forEach(function(d) {
    nn++;
});
print("found " + nn);

found 12500000
50170 millis to fetch  // timing logic not included for clarity.
```

The moment we add even one `$match`, however, things slow down significantly on a "time-per-city" basis:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {"city":"C0"}}
]).forEach(function(d) {
    nn++;
});
print("found " + nn);

found 25000
9489 millis to fetch
```

5.3 times faster but only accounting for 1/500th of the cities!  So if we were to put this in a loop and ask for cities `C0` through `C499`, it stands to reason it would take roughly 500 * 9.4 seconds, or 4700 seconds or 1 hour, 18 mins.  It turns out that adding additional fields to the `$match` or (slightly) more complex pipeline logic in general does not slow down performance nearly as much as the initial `$match` on a single field.
A Java program on a single thread yields roughly the same performance:

```java
                    Document pquery = new Document();
                    pquery.put("city", "C"+i);

                    MongoCursor<Document> cc = coll.find(pquery).iterator();
                    int j = 0;
                    while(cc.hasNext()) {
                        Document src = cc.next();
                        j++;
                    }

// takes about 9.6 seconds for 1 city.
// 16 cities takes 164 seconds so roughly linear scale.
```

A multithreaded version where each thread operates on a different range of cities scales nicely with number of threads.  16 cities with 4 threads takes 45 seconds; 16 cities with 8 threads **also** takes nearly 45 seconds but is not a surprise given the co-lo client and server and thread capability on the MacBookPro.  100 cities with 4 threads takes 275 seconds, so 275 * 5 = 1375 seconds for 500 cities or about 23 minutes.  The MacBookPro is surprisingly capable and it would require a medium-sized (CPU-wise) AWS instance to bring this under 10 minutes.

In general, therefore, the rule of thumb becomes you can go no faster than a single `$match` per thread if you need to drag the data over to the client.  Larger payloads will obviously reduce the performance further.

Comment: thanks for detailed analysis, I am currently running in AWS lambda and it has only 2 threads, main and worker thread. I will try running local setup.